# Change background from OS X application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

After mastering iOS apps, I'm trying to develop a simple OS X application but this doesn't seem to be as easy as I'd have expected.

I've made some successful experiences such as adding a button to the XIB and changing its title within the appdelegate.m, or adding a click event handler, well...

The app has the following structure :

Window > View

I'm trying to change the view's background using this :

```
self.nameOfTheView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(255, 0, 0, 0.9);
```

in the `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` method but nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: AFAIR - you have to tell views to use layers (which is on by default on iOS). Check if layer property is not nil.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Where do I check/Correct that ?

Comment: I think it's the last tab in view's property inspector (Cmd + Alt + 7 when view is selected)